# The object gets blocked by the background in Spark AR

Tags: augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

I have a Spark AR effect with custom background (which is masked out where a person is detected).
I have also a 3d object attached in front of the user forehead.
The problem is that the object gets hidden when the user goes slightly farther from the camera, because(?) the view gets blocked by the custom background which becomes closer to the camera than the object.
Is there a way to keep the object fully visible, no matter how far the user goes from the camera?

[image: textPlane is the object with 3d texts]

The only workaround I can make up is to prevent the z coordinate from being less than zero, but it's far from ideal, because I need to keep the object at the same distance to the forehead.

Answer (score 2):

You need to uncheck "Use Depth Test" and "Write to Depth Test" in the material for the object you would like to remain visible.

[image: Advanced Render Options]

In the Scene hierarchy, move the object above your canvas/background.
[image: Scene Hierarchy]

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, but this does not work on me. The object is still not visible after doing both changes.

Comment: @Coatl please post screenshots of your hierarchy, that will help to clarify the problem.

Comment: OK, I inserted the image into the original question. *textPlane* is the object with 3d texts I wanted to have in front of the *background* and *user* forehead. It is not visible, no matter where I place it in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

so on the material property u will see Advance render option and if u click it u will see " use depth first " and u have to uncheck it . make sure ur rectangle is before the bg rectangle

Comment: 1. Which material do I need to modify? The background, or the object? 2. The object is BEHIND the background most of the time, that's the reason why it is blocked by the backgroud. I'd like to have it visible even if it's behind the background (which needs to be at the z-index 0 I suppose).

Comment: This answer is mostly correct, see mine below for details/screencaps.